# How to use form tag in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use form tag in laravel framework as below

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo 'SongController@savenew';?>">
```

but after submitting it gives me an error

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the [CSRF token](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection) in your form like this:

> Laravel makes it easy to protect your application from cross-site request forgeries. Cross-site request forgeries are a type of malicious exploit whereby unauthorized commands are performed on behalf of the authenticated user.
>
> Laravel automatically generates a CSRF "token" for each active user session managed by the application. This token is used to verify that the authenticated user is the one actually making the requests to the application. To generate a hidden input field _token containing the CSRF token, you may use the csrf_field helper function:
>
> ```
> <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
> ```

Comment: Please can your write a full form example. I make what you suggested but it gives me another error "MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 201:"

Answer (score 1):

Laravel form request always required csrf token

Used

```
<Form method="post" action="">
{{ csrf_field() }}
</Form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Laravel's form builder. Because it requires a CSRF(Cross-site Request Forgery) token, but when you create the form manually the token isn't added to the html, you have to add the token manually 
`ie. <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">`, 
but it is a little safer to use Laravel's standard:

```
<?= Form::open(['controller' => 'SongController@savenew', 'method' => 'POST']); ?>

<?= Form::close(); ?>
```

If you're using blade(**Recommended**):

```
{!! Form::open(['controller' => 'SongController@savenew', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}

{!! Form::close(); !!}
```

Comment: `Form` is not Laravel 5 standard. It was dropped by Taylor. The OP can opt for `laravelcollective/html` in Laravel 5.

Comment: When I was studying a latest tutorial for laravel 5 on tutsplus, this way was recommended. Any idea why it was dropped?

Comment: Taylor commented in a podcast that `Form` and `Html` facades are just html snippet generators and end up being highly community opinionated. No matter how you do it, there will be masses complaining all the time. It wasn't worth the time and energy.

Comment: Laravel collective has been discontinued :(